# Locking Computer or screen timing out results in Black/Blank Screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, login-screen, lock-screen

Issue: Locking Computer or screen timing out results in Black/Blank Screen. Then I try to log back in, the screen remains black and no login screen is displayed.

Environment: 
1. Alienware laptop with a discrete and dedicated graphics cards (GTX and Intel).
2. Issue happens with varies linux distros, currently have ubuntu installed.
3. Linux is installed on a separate Hard Drive. Not Sure where Grub is installed.

The issue happens when I do (Win + L). This issue is not present when starting the computer. Also, If I have the second monitor attached, I can see the ubuntu purple screen on the second monitor and not the laptop's monitor.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: We need a couple of facts to get started. Can you update your question with the results of the commands `uname -r` and `lsb_release -d`? Also is your laptop an AW17R4, etc? Is it a GTX 1060, etc? Do you have an i7-7700 or i7-8700, etc? Are you running `prime-select intel` or `prime-select nvidia`? Whichever one you are running, did you try the other `prime-select`?

Comment: Yes this is AW 17 R4 uname-r --> 4.13.0-39-generic  lsb_release -d --> Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: prime-select is not installed, is that my problem?

Comment: No it's not your problem. It just means you are using the `nouveau` open source drivers and not the `nVidia` proprietary drivers. I'm not really an expert in this area. I've only noticed what information the experts here need to gather to answer questions. So I'm only trying to get you to provide more information for them.

Comment: For the other info, I have I7-7700HW and GTX1070. I tried to install prime-select and disable UEFI. Still the same issue

Comment: UEFI works fine. There are old posts where UEFI and secure boot doesn't work but they do now. Sometimes you need to ignore old threads and focus on new ones.

Comment: I tried to enable prime-select nvidia I got this error. Also thank alot for your time and replies.  Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', None]
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled

Comment: No need to thank me I haven't done much. We are kind of like kinsmen because I have an AW17R3 w/i7-6700HQ and GTX 960M. I keep nVidia turned off in Linux and only use Intel HD 530 Graphics which is faster and problem free for me. I only use the nVidia when I dual boot into Windows 10 and run games every few months or so.

Comment: I installed Xscreensaver and the problem went away. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an answer on how you installed and configured `Xscreensaver` with a summary of how it solves the problem? This will help others with the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please use this link for complete reference. But I installed Xscreensaver and I also uninstalled the pre-installed screensaver that came with ubuntu. https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-autostart-xscreensaver-ubuntu-16-04-16-10#disqus_thread  Install XScreenSaver from Ubuntu Repository or PPA

sudo apt install xscreensaver
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hda-me/xscreensaver
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install xscreensaver
xscreensaver --help  
remove gnome-screensaver 
sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue on Ubuntu 22.04, 5.15.0-41-generic, i12700K integrated graphics, Asus pg32uq. NOT a laptop. Single monitor on HDMI port. The issue was very bad when the monitor was connected to two computers through two different HDMI ports. Linux was practically unusable. The other computer has windows 10 installed and works perfectly with this monitor.

After pressing Super-L the lock screen may not appear. The monitor starts showing "No signal" periodically. Frantically switching between terminals (Ctrl-Alt-Fx) seems to help in a minute or two.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1238762)